# psc had add to the path, but pulp still can't find psc

Tags: purescript

I had install the `psc` by stack, and then install `pulp` and bower by `npm`.

When I run the command `'pulp init'` the output info is

> "* ERROR: `psc` executable not found.".

I find `psc` in the `"~/stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-4.1/7.10.3/bin/"`, so I add it to the path.

I can run the `psc` command now, but `pulp` also can't find `psc`.

What can I do in this situation? Any one can give me some tips?

Comment: Sorry, but the easiest solution would probably be to just install `purescript` from npm, and it should install the correct thing for your distro and have it available through your npm binaries dir. Is there anything preventing you from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Your pulp version is too old. Install the newest one via npm.